# Waiting without waiting in Livecode?

Tags: livecode

I create game matched. I have problem with command "wait". My process is when I drag object to object if it's match the object 1 is hide and wait 2 secs. While I wait I can drag the object to another. But problem is if I drag object 1 to object 2 it will wait 2 secs after that object 2 is hide and I wait 1 secs after that I drag object 3 to object 4 it wait 2 secs after that object 4 is hide. If I do it together object 2 is hide with object 4.

And this my code:

```
on mouseUp
  --check object if match
  wait 2 seconds with messages
  --object hide
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question entirely, but from what I understand, you want to execute some syntax if two objects match while being able to continue to play your game. Here's some code that shows how to do it.

```
on mouseDown
  set the loc of me to the mouseLoc
end mouseDown

on mouseUp
  if match() then
    killOldMessages
    hide me
    send "doSomething" to me in 2 seconds
  end if
end mouseUp

on killOldMessages
  put the pendingMessages into myMessages
  repeat for each line myMsg in myMessages
    if myMsg contains the long id of me and myMsg contains "doSomething" then
      cancel item 1 of myMsg
    end if
  end repeat
end killOldMessages

on doSomething
  if match() then
    // execute this script
  end if
end doSomething
```

Essential is that you check if your objects match two times: one time when you send the message and again when the message is received. In this case, the message is doSomething.

Also, you probably want the doSomething handler to execute only once, even if the user caused multiple messages during the past, say, 6 seconds. The killOldMessages handler makes sure that doSomething isn't executed multiple times after another.

Answer (score 0):

The following change night do what you need..

```
on mouseUp
  -- check object if match
  send "hideMe" to me in 2 seconds
end mouseUp


on hideMe
  hide me
end hideMe
```

that's written for the object's script.

You could also code it at the card level..

```
on mouseUp
  -- check object if match
  put the long id of the target into tTarget
  send "hideObject tTarget" to this card in 2 seconds
end mouseUp


on hideObject pObject
  hide pObject
end hideObject
```